# How to obtain a complex number value?

Tags: java, complex-numbers

This is my code...

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MyFirstClass {

    private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner( System.in );

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {



        System.out.println("Enter the value of Thickness of diaphram ");
        double hd = scanner.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Enter the value of side length of diaphram ");
        double ad = scanner.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Enter the value of hole fraction of diaphram ");
        double kh = scanner.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Enter the value of overlapping Area of diaphram ");
        double A = scanner.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Enter the value of air  gap of diaphr`enter code here`am ");
        double haint = scanner.nextDouble();

        double  Ed= (160* Math.pow(10, 9));
        double vd=(0.2);
        int rhod=2300;
        double Eo=  8.854*Math.pow(10,-12);
        double pi = (3.142857142857412857412857412);



        double Fres = (hd/(2*pi*(Math.pow(ad, 2)))*(Math.sqrt((Ed/(0.02436*((1-(Math.pow(vd,2)))*rhod))))));



        double D =((Ed *(Math.pow(hd,3))) /(12*(1- (Math.pow(vd, 2)))));
        double Vb = 5.225 *(Math.sqrt((Ed*(Math.pow(hd, 3))*(Math.pow(haint, 3)))/((1-(Math.pow(vd, 2)))*Eo*(Math.pow(ad, 4)))));
        double M = ((0.00203*Eo*(Math.pow(ad, 4))*(Math.pow(Vb, 2))) / (4*D));
        double haeff = (haint/3)*(1+ 2* Math.cos((.33* (Math.acos((1 - ((27*M)))/(Math.pow(haint, 3)))))));
        double Cm=Math.abs(((Eo*(1-kh)*A)/(haeff)));

        double Se=((0.09274*(Math.pow(ad,2)))*(Math.sqrt(1-(Math.pow(vd, 2))))*(Math.sqrt(haint)))/((Math.sqrt(Ed))*(Math.pow(hd, 1.5))*(Math.sqrt(Eo)));       

                System.out.println("Fres = "+Fres);

                System.out.println("Capacitance = "+Cm);
                System.out.println("Sensitivity = "+Se);

    }
}
```

Here I am not getting output for the 'Cm' parameter as it give 'NaN'. Here in the 'haeff' parameter I'm getting a complex value but how to get its value and feed it in 'Cm' parameter.

This is the MATLAB code and it's answer....

```
clc;
clear all;
hd=input('Thickness of the diameter = ');
ad= input('side length of the diaphram=');
kh= input('hole fraction= ');
A= input('Overlapping area=');
haint= input('Initial air gap between diaphram and back plate=');
Ed= 160* (10^9);
vd=.2;
rhod=2300;
Eo= 8.854 * 10^-12;
% --------------Resonant Frequancy Start line---------------
Fres = (hd/(2*pi*(ad^2)))*(sqrt(Ed/(0.02436*(1-(vd^2))*rhod))) %resonant freq
% --------------Resonant Frequancy End line---------------

% --------------Capacitance Start Line ---------------------
D = (Ed *(hd^3)) /(12*(1- (vd^2)));
Vb = 5.225 *sqrt((Ed*(hd^3)*(haint^3))/((1-(vd^2))*Eo*(ad^4)));
M = ((0.00203*Eo*(ad^4)*(Vb^2)) / (4*D))
haeff =  (haint/3)*(1+ 2* cos(.33* acos(1 - ((27*M)/(haint^3)))))

Cm=abs((Eo*(1-kh)*A)/(haeff))%Capacitance 
% -----------------Capacitance End Line-------------------

% --------------Sensitivity Start Line ---------------------
Se=(0.09274*(ad^2)*sqrt(1-(vd^2))*sqrt(haint))/((sqrt(Ed)*(hd^1.5))*(sqrt(Eo)))
```

And it's answer is as follows

```
Thickness of the diameter = 2.3e-6
side length of the diaphram=2e-6
hole fraction= .8
Overlapping area=3e-6
Initial air gap between diaphram and back plate=.8

Fres =

   4.9913e+09


M =

    0.0851


haeff =

   0.5946 + 0.3110i


Cm =

   7.9169e-18


Se =

   7.8304e-05
```

Comment: First check for a small number whether it is giving the excepted result and then try for large number

Comment: Please post an [MCVE](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - all of the user input code here probably isn't relevant to your problem, and makes it impossible for us to replicate your issue as we don't know what values you are entering. Please edit your code to hard-code values for each of these variables which ends up giving you Cm=NaN .

Comment: You are getting a 'complex' value in a double? Maybe try writing a class that supports complex numbers? (if you would need the imaginary part) e.g: https://www.math.ksu.edu/~bennett/jomacg/c.html 
And work with this. Java does not have operator overloading so you might need to use methods to do the required calculations. (Not that this explains your problem btw)

Comment: Without knowing your input, it's impossible to say what's going wrong.  But a bit of dimensional intuition suggests that you've messed up the parentheses on the line that starts `double haeff =`.  You may want to double check those parentheses.

Comment: I am posting the matlab code of the same and it's answer..

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that in the following line:

> double haeff = (haint/3)*(1+ 2* Math.cos((.33* (Math.acos((1 -
>   ((27*M)))/(Math.pow(haint, 3)))))));

...the following operation:

> (1 - ((27*M)))/(Math.pow(haint, 3))

...is probably returning negative numbers not in the range of `[-1, +1]` (I tested with small integers, and it returned -4)

In return the function `Math.acos` in the following snippet:

> Math.acos((1 - ((27*M)))/(Math.pow(haint, 3)))

...returns `NAN` (simple trigonometry). Therefore rendering the value of `haeff` to NAN, and by consequence

> double Cm=Math.abs(((Eo*(1-kh)*A)/(haeff)));

...which uses the value of `haeff` will be `NAN`.